# Is there a way to make sure your CSS is cross-browser capable?

Tags: css

Is there a way to make sure your CSS is cross-browser capable?

Comment: Test it in different browsers.

Comment: I agree with Shaggy if you are able to give us some more specific information about exactly what you are building we can create some more catered responses to help you!

Comment: Everyone got a +1, Good going Buddies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to work with strict doctypes, which solves a lot of problems.

Study http://www.quirksmode.org/ by Peter-Paul Koch

I refer to this site all the time.

However, as Ernest Friedman-Hill wisely pointed out, testing...

Answer (score 2):

No, not absolutely sure, unfortunately. Testing, testing, and more testing is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few tips:

- Try not to use CSS3 (yet).
- Don't use browser specific selectors, such as ones prefixed by -moz- or -webkit-
- Use a CSS reset, like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Why not use CSS3 and why not use prefixes? I've just completed a full CSS3 powered website with the help of CSS3 Pie.

Comment: Yeah personally I use CSS3 in all my websites, then i check in older browsers and if it doesn't look too bad without the rounded corners or the gradient I keep moving on :)

Comment: Well, I guess that you can use CSS3 now, especially since IE9 is officially released. However, many people (especially the 'uninformed') still use older browsers. Imo, you also shouldn't hack your way using prefixes like moz/webkit.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do that.

First you will want to check on a few browsers when you are done with your website. Some good options to do that is Adobe Browser application, another is browsershots.com and you can find others.

Another great rule of thumb is to use an established framework that is already cross-browser (my favorite being 52framework at http://52framework.com ).

And honestly after years of writing CSS it seems that you will just get use to writing the best possible CSS and you will have cross-browser code of the get go.

There really is no sure way to write perfect CSS first time around (there are validators out there that can help a little, Dreamweaver has a specific tool that will validate code and CSS and let you know if its capable or not.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to test in each of the browsers you want to support.  If you don't have access to all the browsers there are for-pay web sites that will take screen shots of your site using different browsers:

http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean "capable" or "compatible"?

Anyway, I always use the [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). It checks your CSS to make sure it is valid. After passing this validator, chances are your CSS is cross-browser compatible. But I would recommend also manually inspecting your CSS in different browsers. Do check out http://www.css3.info/ for details on how different browsers implement different features of CSS 3.

I would also recommend you install the [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) if you're planning on doing heavy web development. Great tool for Firefox and Chrome.